# Accumulation points of random walk on $\mathbb{R}^n$ induced by the affine group

Tags: reference-request, random-walks

Let $S_d$ be the group of affine similarities on $\mathbb{R}^d$. An element of $S_d$ is $g=(a,k,b)$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}^*_+, k\in O(d),b\in \mathbb{R}^d$.  The group's multiplication is defined by
\begin{align*}
g_1\cdot g_2=(a_1,k_1,b_1)\cdot (a_2,k_2,b_2)=(a_1a_2,k_1k_2, a_1k_1. b_2+b_1).
\end{align*}
Let $\nu$ be a probability measure on $S_d$, and let $(X_n)_n=(A_n,K_n,B_n)_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. $\nu$ random variables. This measure induces a (left) random walk on $\mathbb{R}^d$ by 
$$
L_k=X_kL_{k-1},
$$
where $L_0=y$ for some $y\in \mathbb{R}^d$. We assume the following on $\nu$:

- It is *centered*, in the sense that $\mathbb{E}[\log(A_n)]=0$;
- It is non-trivial, in the sense that for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$: $\mathbb{P}[X_n\cdot y=y]<1$ and $\mathbb{P}[A_n=1]<1$;
- It has logarithmic moment, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\log(A_n)]<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[\log^+(B_n)]<\infty$.

Let $A(y,\omega)\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be the set of accumulation points of each trajectory. I came across a claim that the set $A(y,\omega)$ is almost surely non-empty, and in fact, does not depend on $y$ nor on $\omega$.

**That is, there exists a set $A$ such that $A=A(y,\omega)$ for every $y$ and almost every $\omega$.**

I'm looking for a reference for a proof. The author (S. Brofferio) only referred to a work by L. Elie, which is in French.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, I think we need to include the requirement $Eb=0$ in the definition of "centered," otherwise this looks totally hopeless. But even then, this setup includes the classical RW on $\mathbb Z^d$ as a special case, which is transient for $d\ge 3$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling By "non-triviality" I meant to exclude this case, and other trivial cases as well. Perhaps I should be more clear. I'll add the exact assumption now, thanks!

Comment: @ChristianRemling Is it clearer now?

Comment: You wanted a reference and not an analysis, but my feeling now is that the rotation part is irrevelant (by compactness of the unit sphere) and the $1D$ toy model where we dilate by $\log A=\pm 1$ or shift by $B=1$ (let's say with prob $1/3$ each) captures the essence of this. I've deleted an answer where I misanalyzed this model.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for your reply. Note that by considering the logarithm of the RW you described, you get the classic simple RW on $\mathbb{R}$ with an error term (the shift) which is exponentially small w.r.t the current location of the random walk. This walk is recurrent, at least in the sense that it visits large enough intervals infinitely many times. (the intervals must be large enough so the walk will not be able to "jump" over them)

Comment: @ChristianRemling The work I'm talking about is 
http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~broff/articoli/rwreal-cor.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This answer is due to Sara Brofferio, the author of the above statement, which kindly responded in private communication.

There is a full proof of the above (and with much background) in:

M. Peigné and W. Woess: *Stochastic dynamical systems with weak contractivity properties, I. Strong and local contractivity. With a chapter featuring results of Martin Benda*, Colloquium Math. 125 (2011) 31-54.